# Calling a function as a function in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wanting to know what is the quickest way below to repeat or give this "function" below a name so that I can call it within another function in the same document -> `runThisFunction();`

**Code:**

```
$('body').on("click", ".manufacturer_details_link", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var self = $(this);
                var id = self.data("id");

                var url = $("#manufacturers_table").data("infourl");

                var data_array = { 
                        id : id 
                    };

                ajaxCall(url, data_array, "rhs_info");

            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood everything correct:

```
function bodyOnClick( e, optionalId ) {
    var nodeRef = optionalId ? document.getElementById( optionalId ) : this;

    if( typeof e === 'object' )
        e.preventDefault();

    var self = $(this);
    var id = nodeRef.data("id");

    var url = $("#manufacturers_table").data("infourl");

    var data_array = { 
        id : id 
    };

    ajaxCall(url, data_array, "rhs_info");
}

// ---

$('body').on("click", ".manufacturer_details_link", bodyOnClick );

// ---

bodyOnClick( 'someNodeID' );
```

<strike>But actually, calling `bodyOnClick` plain doesn't make much sense, since `this` would not reference any *HTMLElement*. So it only makes sense if you re-use the method on other event handlers, or explicitly call it like</strike>

```
bodyOnClick.call( someNodeReference );
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, would I pass in an id as nodeRef?

Comment: @JessMcKenzie No, it has to be an actual node. I.e. `$("#foo")[0]`

Comment: @JessMcKenzie you could do that, but you would need to re-write the function for that, I edited the function to give you a basic example.

Comment: @jAndy I'd suggest not reusing the bind handler, it makes for some unreadable code. I'd split them up into two functions, leaving the bind handler as a lamba function and calling the other function from within that one.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall I guess I would agree in general. However, I think the answer here makes some good enough points and examples so ultimately OP and others will realize your note for themselfs :-)

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
function someFunction(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data("id"),
        url = $("#manufacturers_table").data("infourl"),
        data_array = {id: id};
    ajaxCall(url, data_array, "rhs_info");
}
//$('.manufacturer_details_link').click(someFunction);

// changed, per feedback
$('.manufacturer_details_link').on('click', someFunction);
```

Comment: OP is using `.on` since it's a delegated bind. Don't change it unless you know it will work.